# Why is Euclidean Norm required when argument is squared anyway?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, normed-spaces

In k-means clustering, the following expression is evaluated

$$ \arg \min \sum_{i=1}^k \sum_{x \in \bf{S}_i} \left|\left| \bf{x}-\bf{\mu}_
i \right|\right|^2$$

Why is the taking the norm required when $\bf{x}-\bf{\mu}$ is squared anyway?
Is the norm required, because without it would not be explicit, that it's a distance between two vectors which is squared?

Comment: It doesn't have to be squared.

Comment: Please explain, wikipedia wrong? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering

Comment: Please see: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/112698/using-k-means-with-other-metrics

Answer (score 1):

A vector cannot be squared. Real numbers can.

That being said, life would of course be miserable without canonical (!) implicit notation. Squaring a vector, however,  is not canonical at all. Indeed, I would bet that no one has ever used that notation in an article. For a good reason: the norm to be squared might not be obvious,  and some might also think squaring a vector means taking the square of each component.

Comment: Then how exactly should the expression look like?

Comment: As you wrote it in your question. I am not sure if I got your question right,  but I assumed you were asking if it was necessary to write the norm before the squaring, or if one could just write $ (x-\mu_i)^2$ instead

Comment: Thats exactly what I was asking about. And the squaring is required to not end up with negative distances, correct?

Comment: @TMOTTM No, squaring is not required to not end with negative distances. A norm per definition is non-negative.

Comment: So either one squares, or one norms? Or to be on the safe side, does both?

Comment: It is simple: $(x-\mu_i)^2$ is not defined. So you can only take $\|x-\mu_i\|^2$ or $\|x-\mu_i\|$. Which of the two you choose depends on the application, and I can not say about that choice. But again: if you choose the first option, $\|x-\mu_i\|^2$, you cannot instead write $(x-\mu_i)^2$, because it is not defined.

Comment: Alright, I understand and it's what I thought.